# How do I put a UIViewController in a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

Currently, I have a seemingly redundant setup(partly because I can't get it to work) to successfully have a table of ViewControllers.

See this line of code:

```
cell.cardView.cardController.task = task
```

before I had:

```
cell.cardController.task = task
```

both give me:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

[image]

Comment: I did my best to research this.. I just posted because I am really not sure what to do

Comment: @Losiowaty I did see that post

Comment: Was everything clear there? Have you checked all variables used in your statement  (since there is no `!` there, I assume that at least one of them is declared as `var variable: Type!`)? A wild guess would be that its `cardView` and that its an outlet from a `xib` and you are trying to use it before it has been setup (i.e. before `awakeFromNib` has been called). Am I right?

Comment: Yes.  Everything is clear now.  I just can't see my views now  -_-'           thanks